# Download draw.io diagram as file.drawio

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm wondering if it's possible to download a draw.io diagram with the format file.drawio directly from the app.diagrams.net interface.

[image]

Comment: File->Save As->Enter filename->Click download.

Comment: Hello @ThomastheTankEngine there isn't Save As

Comment: Try export as instead

Comment: @ThomastheTankEngine no .drawio extension in export

Comment: XML is the same thing. Just give it a .drawio suffix if you prefix.

Comment: @ThomastheTankEngine thank you very much for your precious suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### Steps

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for `Save As` and then click on `Download` or `Device`.

[image]

###### Version

- https://app.diagrams.net/
- Version 20.7.4
- Screenshot
  [image]

###### Confluence

If you happen to use Draw.io inside Confluence, there might not be a `Save As` option. In that case, use

1. `File` → `Export as` → `XML...`
   [image]
2. `Export`

   [image]
3. In the `Save as` dialog, click `Download`
   [image]

   You can remove the `.xml` extension and just keep the `.drawio` extension if you want.

Comment: Hello @Lenkurve in my menu there is only the option Save

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I see in your screenshot now that you indeed only have `Save`. Can you check what version you have? I've added the link, the version and a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: the version is 20.8.5

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Ah! Could it be that your are using Draw.io inside Confluence?

Comment: what is it? If it is a way to allow edit to many users the answer is no

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Ok, I've added another section and a few screenshots to the answer. Hope that helps. Instead of `Save as`, one can use `Export as`.

Comment: Hi @Lernkurve thank you very much for your amazing solution.